# Fullscreen toggle seems to instantly go back again

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm new to python and i was trying to let the 1-button on the keyboard toggle fullscreen in an application using pygame. Somehow the else: statement causes it to instantly go back to windowed mode again. At least that is my understanding. Can anyone enlighten me why that happens and care to give an alternative method?
This is the code:

```
# screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
# fullscreen = False
if event.key == K_1:
    if fullscreen == False:
        pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768), FULLSCREEN)
        fullscreen = True
    else:
        pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
        fullscreen = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're checking each frame to see if your event key (`K_1`) is being held. Instead, you probably want to check for a KEY_UP or KEY_DOWN event. I'm not familiar with pygame - but I assume you could probably get that sort of information out of your `event` variable.

Alternatively, keep a variable that detects when you're still holding the key - which may look something like this:

```
# outside of the loop code
holding_fullscreen = false

# inside the loop code
if event.key == K_1:
    if not holding_fullscreen:
        holding_fullscreen = true
        if not fullscreen:  # more pythonic version of fullscreen == False
            # set fullscreen
        else:
            # set windowed
else:
    holding_fullscreen = False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was indeed triggering multiple times within the same pressing. Using KEYUP fixed that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is inside your loop. If so, every time the game refreshes, it will check for an input, and when it sees that K_1 is not pressed, fullscreen will be disabled again. You'd have to constantly hold done K_1. You need to just remove the else.

Comment: He wants to toggle between fullscreen and not. Taking out the else statement would surely break the toggle.